# How to check if object is insert or update upon save in python 2.7 django

Tags: python-2.7, django-admin

```
def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
    if self._state.adding is True:
        super(TaskAdmin, self).save_model(request, obj, form, change)
    else:
        if 'hours_per_day' in form.changed_data:
            messages.info(request, "Hours per Day has changed.")

            if date.today():
                TaskHourChange.objects.filter(date_changed=date.today()).delete()
            taskchange = TaskHourChange.objects.create(
                date_changed=date.today(), prev_hours_per_day=obj.hours_per_day, task=obj)
            taskchange.save()
        else:
            messages.info(request, "Hours per Day has not changed")
        super(TaskAdmin, self).save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```

I tried this and it doesn't work. I want to check if the object is updated or inserted.

Answer (score 1):

Check if `change==True` (preferred) or `obj.pk is None`. A `ModelAdmin` class is stateless. An instance of the `ModelAdmin` class is attached to the `site` and it doesn't and shouldn't hold the state of processing the request.